# Measure time of query in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, time, sql-execution-plan

How can I measure execution time of query in MongoDB ?
I found Mongo-hacker plugin but it looks like it measure time of query including  time of displaying all results.
In PostgreSQL I use Explain Analyze SELECT ... , but i didn't found any information about time in mongo's  db.collection.find({smth}).explain()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the profiling level in MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Once you've done this, details on all of your queries will be logged to the system profile table.

Answer (score 84):

You can add `.explain("executionStats")` at the end of the query.

Comment: If you need execution stats for an `aggregate` query, look here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758

Comment: What about measuring execution time of insert operation?

Comment: How to find execution time for updateOne operation ?

Answer (score 2):

**Using Robo 3T and this worked for me in aggregation** -

```
db.getCollection('product_verification').explain("executionStats").aggregate([
{$match: {"company_id":1}},
{$lookup: {
    "from": "product",
    "let": {"company": "$company_id", "code": "$item_code"},
    "pipeline": [
       {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
           {"$eq": ["$company_id", "$$company"]},
           {"$eq": ["$item_code", "$$code"]},
           {"$in": ["$brand_uid",[13, 20]]}
           ]}
           }}
    ],
    "as": "details"
    }}])
```

**And when using not aggregation**

```
db.getCollection('product').find({name: "lenovo"}).explain("executionStats")
```